# Bending of light Ray in radially varying refractive index

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, refraction, geometric-optics

If light passes near a massive object, the gravitational interaction causes a bending of the ray. This can be thought of as happening due to a change in the effective refrative index of the medium given by
$$n(r) = 1 + 2 \frac{GM}{rc^2}$$
where $r$ is the distance of the point of consideration from the centre of the mass of the massive body, G is the universal gravitational constant, M the mass of the body and c the speed of light in vacuum. Considering a spherical object find the deviation of the ray from the original path as it grazes the object.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122319/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Solve the eikonal  in spherical coordinates.